# Give edit rights on new Stack Exchange to user that have edit rights on other sites

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-exchange

I am seeing a problem with a lot of the new Stack Exchange sites. There are not enough users with edit rights to make the clear and simple edits that are needed. So we are getting lots of comment asking for edits.

Therefore I think, while a site is in beta, any user that has over XYZ rep on another site should be given edit rights. By the time the site comes out of beta enough users should have gained edit rights on the site itself – otherwise the beta is ending too soon.

Comment: Reputation requirements are already much lowered on stackexchanges.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58605/dont-apply-new-user-behaviors-on-a-new-site-when-the-user-has-sufficient-experie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All users (even anonymous users) can now [suggest edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work) to posts.

This gives users without explicit edit rights the chance to improve the sites' content through a peer-review process (see the link for more information).

Answer (score 8):

No.

Why not?

Because some rights like close and edit require **domain** knowledge not knowledge of how Stack Exchange works.

While I know quite a bit about programming and using computers, I'm not so hot on administering servers or websites. So while I might be able to contribute some knowledge I haven't demonstrated that I know enough to be able to edit questions or vote to close.

Comment: but you know how to fix a spelling/tagging error, and should know what you don't know.  However I tend to agree with "close" rights

Comment: @Ian - unfortunately an edit is a edit and system can't *easily* tell the difference between correcting the spelling/grammar/code format and changing the meaning of a post.